# adding equation to the R plot

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering how I can paste the following equation as legend or text box to my plot in R (shown below in Latex format):

```
$$
x_i\stackrel{{\rm iid}}{\sim}{\rm Normal}\big(\mu-\frac \alpha 2,\sigma^2\big),\quad i = 1,\ldots, N_x  \\  
y_i\stackrel{{\rm iid}}{\sim}{\rm Normal}\big(\mu+\frac \alpha 2,\sigma^2\big),\quad i = 1,\ldots, N_y  
$$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following

```
library(latex2exp)
plot(TeX("$x_i$ \t $\\overset{iid}{\\sim}$ \t $Normal$ 
          $\\left(\\mu -\\frac{\\alpha}{2} ,\\sigma^2\\right)$,\t$i = 1,\\ldots, N_x$"))
```

to get the following

[image]